# Error while running sbt-native-packager debian package on ubuntu

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) to create a `debain` package of my `scala` application. Everything was working and one fine morning, I started to get the below error when trying to start the application.

> Reserved character '+' is not allowed outside quotes

```
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse: reference.conf: 3: Reserved character '+' is not allowed outside quotes (if you intended '+' to be part of the value for 'modules', try enclosing the value in double quotes)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.nextToken(Parser.java:178)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseKey(Parser.java:487)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseObject(Parser.java:587)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseValue(Parser.java:424)
```

I was building the debain through `Jenkins`. I tried building the debian from my machine and uploaded to the server. With that, it started to work. I thought it could be something to do with the jenkins and ignored it and used another jenkins for the builds. Suddenly, yesterday night, I started to get the same error in this new jenkins as well. I am not sure what is the issue. Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

My `build.sbt` file is as below (usign Build.scala for the dependency management):

```
name := "common-api"

version := "0.8.6.4-COLUMNS-SNAPSHOT"

javaOptions  ++= Seq("-javaagent:" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar")

fork := true

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)

packageDescription in Debian := "Common module"

maintainer in Debian := "yadu krishnan"

mainClass in Compile := Some("com.app.common.core.BootService")
```

> Command used to build : sbt compile stage debian:packageBin

Comment: What does reference.conf look like? Any '+' symbols in there?

Comment: I dont have a reference.conf file at all. Have application.conf, but that doesnt have any + symbol

Comment: The error message suggests something else. Read the typesafe config documentation on how to debug the parsing.